# Performance issues when INSERTing in one table, but not another that has many more indexes

Tags: postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table DDLs (names changed):

(note the `UUID` PK)

```sql
CREATE TABLE myschema.item
(
    item_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    ref_id uuid NOT NULL,
    type_id uuid NOT NULL,
    quantity numeric NOT NULL,
    parent_item_id uuid,
    CONSTRAINT item_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_item_ref_id ON myschema.item USING btree (ref_id) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

And:

(note the `bigint` PKs)

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.record
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('record_id_seq'::regclass),
    ref_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT record_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT record_ref_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_id)
        REFERENCES public.ref (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE public.record_item
(
    item_id bigint NOT NULL,
    quantity numeric NOT NULL,
    department_id bigint,
    parent_record_item_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT record_item_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT record_item_department_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
        REFERENCES public.department (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT record_item_ref_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_id)
        REFERENCES public.ref (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT record_item_parent_record_item_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_record_item_id )
        REFERENCES public.record_item (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT record_item_item_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES public.item (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
    INHERITS (public.record)
WITH (OIDS = FALSE)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX record_item_id_idx ON public.record_item USING btree (id) TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX record_item_ref_id_idx ON public.record_item USING btree (ref_id) TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_record_item_create
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.record_item
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.record_create();
```

The details of the trigger are not that relevant: the gist of it is that it checks whether the to-be-added ID exists in any other child table. To my knowledge it exists because of a previous limitation with inheritance in Postgres.

The tables have the following size:

```sql
table_schema  table_name      row_estimate    total    index     table
myschema      item            306989248       56 GB    25 GB     31 GB
public        record_item     332611424       45 GB    21 GB     24 GB
```

These two tables refer to the same kind of object, have rows on the same order of magnitude (~300M) and are both *append-only*. The way the data is stored is slightly different, and the larger size in `item` is (as far as I can tell) mostly owed to the `UUID` keys.

According to our Postgres Analysis Tool (Powa: https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the `INSERT` statements on these tables in any given hour have the following stats:

```sql
Query                                      Avg_time   Blocks_read    Blocks_hit    Blocks_dirtied
INSERT INTO public.record_item (...)         480 µs       42.05 M       83.83 G            1.70 G
INSERT INTO myschema.item (...)          3ms 837 µs        1.54 G        8.40 G            1.58 G
```

---

These numbers don't quite add up for me.

1. Table `myschema.item` has only two indexes: the PK itself and `idx_item_ref_id`, and no FKs.
2. In comparison, table `public.record_item` has:

   - PK index
   - `record_item_id_idx`
   - `record_item_ref_id_idx`
   - A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger
   - inherited from `public.record` (!)
   - four FKs

Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` seems to support this:

```sql
db=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO "myschema"."item" (...) RETURNING "item"."id";
                                             QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on item (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.143..0.145 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.026 ms
 Execution time: 0.169 ms

db=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE INSERT INTO "public"."record_item" (...) RETURNING "record_item"."id";
                                               QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on record_item (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.355..2.358 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.127..0.128 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.065 ms
 Trigger for constraint record_item_department_id_fkey: time=0.551 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint record_item_ref_id_fkey: time=0.736 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint record_item_parent_record_item_id_fkey : time=0.017 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint record_item_item_id_fkey : time=0.386 calls=1
 Trigger trigger_record_item_create: time=1.249 calls=1
 Execution time: 4.254 ms
```

These numbers just don't add up. It's obvious that the second `INSERT` has to do a *lot* more work than the first, yet the averages are an order of magnitude apart in favor of the second `INSERT`.

Since POWA uses build-in Postgres 'metrics' queries (e.g. `pg_stat_statements`), I can't imagine that the numbers are buggy.

Similarly, I have not seen any queries which might end up failing (i.e. exiting immediately) due to an e.g. FK violation.

The only glaring difference that I can see is that the first table uses `UUID` keys and indexes while the latter uses `bigint`, potentially causing page faults / index fragmentation more often when trying to look up / maintain the PK index. However, I currently do not know of way to verify this, although it *could* explain the `Blocks_read` value of the second `INSERT`.

I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone have an idea how I might debug/analyze this situation further?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? `uuid_generate_v4()` is extremely slow on Windows. Even on Linux I see [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.9) being (somewhat) faster than `uuid_generate_v4()`

Comment: The Postgres Cluster is running on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. I'll try switching `uuid_generate_v4()` to `gen_random_uuid()` and see if it makes any difference for a large insertion volume.

Comment: `gen_random_uuid()` is indeed faster by a factor of 4. However, this does not seem to be relevant in this case as all UUIDs are inserted by the application and the default is only a safeguard.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is caching.

The statistics confirm that the insert on `record_item` touches about ten times as many blocks as the insert on `item`. But the latter has to read way more blocks from I/O (1.4 GB vs. 40MB).

Perhaps `record_item` is append-only and all inserts go to the same blocks, while `item` has deleted or updated rows, and the inserts are distributed across more blocks, most of which are not in cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, both tables are append-only and nothing is deleted or updated from either table. Is it possible that data locality plays a role here? E.g. `bigint` PK Index is easier to scan due to being contiguous, `UUID` PK Index data is more "strewn about" and would lead to cache misses more often. Do you know if there is a way to verify this behaviour?

Comment: That would be a good explanation. UUIDs sre not generated in sorting order, so it could be the index.